Does a log-normal distribution tend to an exponential distribution, when increasing its standard deviation?
A log-normal distribution lognorm(mu, sigma) becomes more and more skewed with the increase of its standard deviation sigma.
As sigma increases, does the distribution tend to an exponential distribution exp(lambda) ?
Is there any relationship between the two functions and their parameters ?

"an exponential distribution lognorm(lambda) becomes more and more skewed with the increase of its rate lambda"  looks as if it confuses exponential and lognormal distributions.  All exponential distributions have the same skewness $(2)$ because they only differ in scale.

There is a kind of limiting distribution when suitably normalized, thereby justifying the intuition that underlies this question.  It turns out not to be Exponential, though, nor can it possibly be.
We say a random variable $Y$ has a lognormal distribution when its logarithm $X=\log(Y)$ has a Normal distribution (with, say, mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$).  Intuitively, a Normal distribution with suitably large variance $\sigma$ looks uniform over a wide interval around $\mu;$ so if we make this interval cover primarily negative numbers and exponentiate $X,$ it ought to look like an exponential distribution.  Thus, there is some hope of succceeding.  Let's pursue the details.
A little Calculus tells us the distribution of $Y$ has a density equal to zero for negative numbers $y$ and, for positive $y,$ the density is given by
$$f(y;\mu,\sigma) = \frac{C}{\sigma} \exp\left(-{\frac{(\log(y) - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)\frac{\mathrm dy}{y}$$
where $C$ normalizes the density to integrate to unity.
Write $\mu = \sigma^2 - a$ (so that $a$ reflects the shift in $X$ towards negative values) and compute
$$f(y; \sigma^2-a,\sigma) = \frac{C}{\sigma}\exp\left(-{\frac{(\log(y) +a - \sigma^2)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)\frac{\mathrm dy}{y}.$$
Fix  $y\gt 0$ and take $\sigma$ to be very large as in the question.  Abbreviating $\log(y)=\eta,$ compute
$${\frac{(\eta + a - \sigma^2)^2}{2\sigma^2}} = \frac{\eta^2}{2\sigma^2} + \frac{2(a - \sigma^2)\eta}{2\sigma^{2}}  + \frac{(a-\sigma^2)^2}{2\sigma^2}.$$
What happens in the limit as $\sigma$ grows large?

The first term, $\eta^2/(2\sigma^2),$ vanishes.

The second term is directly proportional to $\eta.$  If this is to have any limit, we must arrange for the ratio $(a - \sigma^2)/\sigma^2$ to have a finite limit.  Let us therefore take $a = \lambda \sigma^2,$ whence the limiting value of the second term is $(\lambda - 1)\eta.$

The third term is part of the normalizing constant because it does not depend on $\eta.$  Let's absorb this into the original normalizing constant and call the whole thing $$\gamma(a,\sigma) = \frac{C}{\sigma}\exp\left(-\frac{(a-\sigma^2)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right).$$


Because the exponential function is continuous, the limits of the exponentials of these terms are the exponentials of the limits. Consequently, the only way in which the limiting value of the density can depend on $y$ is through the second term, which produces a factor of
$$f(y,\sigma^2 - \lambda\sigma^2,\sigma) \propto \exp(-(\lambda - 1)\log(y))\,\frac{\mathrm dy}{y} = y ^{-\lambda}\mathrm dy.$$
This looks like a Pareto distribution, but it is improper because it diverges near $y\approx 0,$ where $\eta = \log(y)$ is very large and negative.
Recalling $y\gt 0$ throughout this analysis, we conclude:

The only possible way in which a sequence of lognormal distributions can have a limiting distribution is to set $\mu = \sigma^2 - a = (1-\lambda)\sigma^2,$ in which case the limit is the improper Pareto distribution with parameter $\lambda$ on the nonnegative real numbers: its "density" is proportional to $y^{-\lambda}.$

To illustrate, for $\lambda = 2$ a value of $\sigma = 3$ is sufficiently large for the approximation to be good over a large range.  Here is a plot of the logarithms of their density functions (black for lognormal, dotted red for the limiting Pareto):

The red (Pareto) density inevitably diverges at $y=0.$  This occurs because the limit (over $\sigma$) is not uniform: as $y$ gets smaller, ever larger values of $\sigma$ are required to approximate the Pareto density at $y.$

Any exponential distribution has constant moment-skewness of $2$.
A lognormal with arbitrarily large $\sigma$ will have arbitrarily large (albeit finite) skewness.
It may be helpful to look at the log of the density of the distribution of the log of each (the log-density of $\log(X)$...)
On this scale, lognormals will be quadratic, where changing $\sigma$ alters the scale, while for the exponential, this is not symmetric, and changing $\lambda$ doesn't change the scale.
[Under whuber's interpretation of what you were seeking in the question, his limiting distribution for the lognormal effectively looks at what happens as you 'zoom in' on a particular sequence of those quadratics in a specific place - where he makes the only choices of the sequence and the place to look that would make much sense in that case.  As you zoom right in, it looks linear, which doesn't match what you get for the exponential.]

I think the skewness argument is persuasive, but the mode argument is not looking at $e^{\mu-\sigma^2} \to 0$ as $\sigma^2$ increases for given $\mu$.

@Henry Fair enough, I'll take that part out

Thanks, I edited the question accordingly

The skewness argument implicitly supposes that skewness is a continuous functional of these distributions--but that ain't necessarily so!

No, this does not happen.  As Glen_b says, the skewness of the lognormal increases rapidly as $\sigma$ increases, while all exponential distributions have a skewness of $2$.
As an illustration suppose you keep the median a constant $1$ as you vary $\sigma$, so  your lognormals with parameter $\mu=0$.  An exponential distribution with the same median would have rate $\lambda=\log_e 2 \approx 0.693$. Here are the densities for the exponential distribution in black, for the lognormal with $\sigma=0.55138358994$ (same skewness of $2$) in pink, $\sigma=1$ in red, $\sigma=2$ in blue, and $\sigma=3$ in green.  You are not getting convergence.

Alternatively suppose you keep the mean a constant $1$ as you vary $\sigma$, so  rescaling your lognormals with parameter $\mu=-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$.  An exponential distribution with the same mean would have rate $\lambda=1$. Here are the densities for the exponential distribution in black, for the lognormal with $\sigma=0.55138358994$ (same skewness of $2$) in pink, $\sigma=1$ in red, $\sigma=2$ in blue, and $\sigma=3$ in green.  Again you are not getting convergence.


You can make progress by simultaneously changing the geometric mean with the variance, as intuition would suggest.  This would somewhat parallel other limiting approaches such as simultaneously varying $n$ and $p$ to obtain a Poisson distribution as a limit of Binomial$(n,p)$ distributions.

@whuber  I think the geometric mean of a lognormal distribution is its median.  How would you change it with the variance?

As described in my answer here, you need the difference between the GM and geometric variance to be constant ( at least asymptotically).  This is the only way that can possibly work.
